# postgresql migration

Tags: java, sql, migration

hi I have this in my entity it is enum so in my db it saves as ordinal 1 or 0

```
@Column(name = "status")
private ClientStatusEnum status;
```

and this is my migration

```
 CREATE TABLE public.clients
(
id bigserial NOT NULL,
created_at        timestamp    NOT NULL,
removed           bool         NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
removed_at        timestamp    NULL,
updated_at        timestamp    NULL,
authorities       varchar(255) NULL,
last_active_at    timestamp    NULL,
logged_in_at      timestamp    NULL,
"password"        varchar(255) NULL,
username          varchar(255) NULL,
image_url         varchar(255) NULL,
"name"            varchar(255) NULL,
phone_number      varchar(255) NULL,
status int4 NULL, /////////////////////////////this is status //////////
surname           varchar(255) NULL,
profile_image_url varchar(255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT clients_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

);

Now i've changed this to this one

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
@Column(name = "status")
private ClientStatusEnum status;
```

to save it as string

so i need to write migraion like above to change tht in status to this new status type ,
but i have clients whose statuses are 0 or 1 i need to write sql in migration file in a way that
their statuses : 0 1 change REGISTERED or ACTIVE,and new comers get already this new way status

and this is my enum

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public enum ClientStatusEnum {
REGISTERED,
ACTIVE,
INTEGRATED
```

}

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to write a migration with an additional temporary column where the enumeration values will be written?

Examples of migration commands:

```
alter table public.clients
    add column status_tmp varchar(25);

update public.clients
set status_tmp = 'REGISTERED'
where status = 0;


update public.clients
set status_tmp = 'ACTIVE'
where status = 1;

alter table public.clients
    drop column status;

alter table public.clients
    rename column status_tmp to status;
```

In the entity class above the enumeration field, only the @Enumerated annotation is enough. The @Column annotation is unnecessary because the field in the class matches the name in the database.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ClientStatusEnum status;
```

Comment: listen really thank you so much I'll try this now sure this will work thanks a lot